# jQuery document .off function doesn't unbind events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set up mouseenter and mouseleave events for buttons on the page.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".item-fav-btn", highlightButton);
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".item-fav-btn", removeHighlightButton);
```

In order to unbind those events I access some of the buttons that are with that class but with their IDs like so (that code is inside a loop):

```
$(document).off("mouseenter", "#item-btn-" + id);   
$(document).off("mouseleave", "#item-btn-" + id);
```

The problem is that the events are not removed and still active for that particular element. I think it might be because I've set up event for a class and I try to unbind it using the Id of the element. I need the Id because I only unbind for specific elements and I need the class because I init the events for all buttons, those that exists on the page and those coming after using Ajax.

Is there an option to unbind those events by access a particular element using the Id selector and still maintaining the original class selector based binding?

Comment: You have to use the same target!

Comment: Thanks, @Eric I am aware of this, but wanted to know if there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory about classes vs id is correct.

One solution would be add another class instead of trying to remove the whole listener . Then inside the handler check if that class exists before performing whatever the handler does

---

Alternate solution also adding a class but using a `not()` filter in original event binding to ignore elements you add the new class to

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".item-fav-btn:not(.new-class-name)", highlightButton);
```

Comment: I am aware about the class solution, but I wanted to know if this is possible to do using script.

Comment: I guess you could use `off()` on whole class then add it again but using a `not(.newClass)` to filter out the items you do add a class to

Comment: Or in fact...just use `not()` right from the start....then add a class to items you don't want included as events occur